# Simplify/rewrite integral related to the Gauss kernel

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let's consider the integral
$$
\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-\frac{y}{2\alpha}\cdot x - \frac{|y|^2}{4\alpha}t - \frac{|y|^2}{2}}  d y \right)\left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(z) e^{-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2t}}dz \right)
$$
where $\alpha >0$ and $f$ is smooth and compactly supported.

**Questions:**

1. Can $\Phi$ be manipulated and rewritten in a more explicit/simpler way?
2. Does $\Phi(x,t)$ solve any particular PDE with initial datum $f$?

Comment: If there is no typo in $f(y)$ you can pull that out of the $dz$-integral and replace that by $f(y)(2\pi t)^{n/2}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. There was in fact a typo: it was supposed to be $f(z)$

Comment: Sorry to be so pedantic. Unless there is no typo in $e^{-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2t}}$ you can now pull that entire $dz$-integral out of the $dy$-integral. Also: the first exponential term looks strange. It is not by any chance $e^{-\frac{|y-x|^2}{2\alpha}}$?

Comment: @KurtG. You're right. Indeed, the inner integral does not depend on $y$. The first exponential term is ok

Answer (score 1):

First write
\begin{align}
-\frac{y\cdot x}{2\alpha} - \frac{|y|^2}{4\alpha}t - \frac{|y|^2}{2}&=-\frac{2\,y\cdot x+|y|^2(t+2\alpha)}{4\alpha}=-\frac{\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{t+2\alpha}}+y\sqrt{t+2\alpha}\right|^2-\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{t+2\alpha}}\right|^2}{4\alpha}\,.
\end{align}
The $dy$-integral then becomes after a variable transformation
\begin{align}
\exp\Big(\frac{|x|^2}{4\alpha(t+2\alpha)}\Big)\frac{1}{(t+2\alpha)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp\Big(-\frac{\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{t+2\alpha}}+u\right|^2}{4\alpha}\Big)\,du\,.
\end{align}
Since we are integrating over the entire $\mathbb R^n$ we can drop the constant $\frac{x}{\sqrt{t+2\alpha}}$ so that this integral becomes
\begin{align}
\exp\Big(\frac{|x|^2}{4\alpha(t+2\alpha)}\Big)\frac{1}{(t+2\alpha)^{n/2}}\frac{1}{(4\pi\alpha)^{n/2}}\,.
\end{align}
This should answer question 1. It is known that the $dz$-integral satisfies the heat equation with initial datum $f\,.$ At the moment I don't see a simple PDE that is solved by $\Phi(x,t)\,.$ Where does that problem come from?